# PHP readfile on a file which is increasing in size

Tags: php, download, ffmpeg, wget, readfile

Is it possible to use PHP readfile function on a remote file whose size is unknown and is increasing in size? Here is the scenario:

I'm developing a script which downloads a video from a third party website and simultaneously trans-codes the video into MP3 format. This MP3 is then transferred to the user via readfile.

The query used for the above process is like this:

```
wget -q -O- "VideoURLHere" | ffmpeg -i - "Output.mp3" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

So the file is fetched and encoded at the same time.
Now when the above process is in progress I begin sending the output mp3 to the user via readfile. The problem is that the encoding process takes some time and therefore depending on the users download speed readfile reaches an assumed EoF before the whole file is encoded, resulting in the user receiving partial content/incomplete files.

My first attempt to fix this was to apply a speed limit on the users download, but this is not foolproof as the encoding time and speed vary with load and this still led to partial downloads.

So is there a way to implement this system in such a way that I can serve the downloads simultaneously along with the encoding and also guarantee sending the complete file to the end user?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
In response to Peter, I'm actually using fread(read readfile_chunked):

```
 <?php
 function readfile_chunked($filename,$retbytes=true) {
            $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); // how many bytes per chunk
            $totChunk = 0;
            $buffer = '';
            $cnt =0;
            $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
            if ($handle === false) {
                return false;
            }
            while (!feof($handle)) {
                //usleep(120000); //Used to impose an artificial speed limit
                $buffer = fread($handle, $chunksize);
                echo $buffer;
                ob_flush();
                flush();
                if ($retbytes) {
                    $cnt += strlen($buffer);
                }
            }
                $status = fclose($handle);
            if ($retbytes && $status) {
                return $cnt;        // return num. bytes delivered like readfile() does.
            }
            return $status;
        }
        readfile_chunked($linkToMp3);
    ?>
```

This still does not guarantee complete downloads as depending on the users download speed and the encoding speed, the EOF() may be reached prematurely.

Also in response to theJeztah's comment, I'm trying to achieve this without having to make the user wait..so that's not an option.

Comment: i would try with `fsockopen/fread/feof` instead

Comment: Or create some mechanism to indicate that the encoding has finished and *then* start the download. If encoding fails, you'll end up with an invalid download anyway

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php might be a good candidate too, basically, you're downloading a stream?

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski I updated the question, please recheck.
thaJeztah I'll take  look at that, thank you.

Comment: @thaJeztah
I'll take a look at that, not sure if it'll help though.

Comment: @SathiyaSundaram so I believe all you need to do now is replace `feof($handle)` with some condition checking is the process is complete

Comment: It's an interesting question though, basically it's a "live broadcast" you're downloading as there's no known file size at the time. Therefore you might need to rely on a timeout to know when the download has finished? Not really sure though, just echoing my thoughts and hoping they will assist

Comment: IMO The easiest approach - [Create tmp file while working, delete if after process finish](http://pastebin.com/aNLRpWaG), check in php is file exists instead of `feof`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are dealing with streams, you probably should use stream handling functions :). [passthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) comes to mind, although this will only work if the `download | transcode` command is started in your script.

If it is started externally, take a look at [stream_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php).

Answer (score 1):

Libevent as mentioned by *Evert* seems like the general solution where you *have* to use a file as a buffer. However in your case, you could do it all inline in your script without using a file as a buffer:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
passthru("wget -q -O- http://localhost/test.avi | ffmpeg -i - -f mp3 -");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any of being notified about there being new data, short of something like inotify.

I suggest that if you hit EOF, you start polling the modification time of the file (using `clearstatcache()` between calls) every 200 ms or so. When you find the file size has increased, you can reopen the file, seek to the last position and continue.

Comment: I think this method along with Peter's suggestion of using a temporary file might work best. Time to get coding..

Answer (score -1):

I can highly recommend using libevent for applications like this.

It works perfect for cases like this.

The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.libevent.php) is a bit sparse for this, but you should be able to find more solid examples around the web.

Comment: I don't see how libevent would help here. Can you explain?